# How to convert binary, octal and quaternary lists into decimal lists?

Tags: python, list

I need to convert three lists into decimal lists to check maximum and minimum value in them. How can I do it? example Lists:

```
binary_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 10, 10, 11, 100, 100, 11, 10, 0]

quaternary_list = [-11, -33, -22, -132, -220, -310]

octal_list = [62, -220, -36, 5, 0, 1, -12]
```

Comment: I tried converting individual number before adding it to the list, but it did not work

Comment: You don't need to do any conversions to find mins or maxes. Just use the built-in `min()` and `max()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this ([try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/f9b8381eey)):

```
binary_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 10, 10, 11, 100, 100, 11, 10, 0]
quaternary_list = [-11, -33, -22, -132, -220, -310]
octal_list = [62, -220, -36, 5, 0, 1, -12]

def list_to_decimal(lst, base):
    return [int(str(item), base) for item in lst]

print(list_to_decimal(binary_list, 2)) # => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0]
print(list_to_decimal(quaternary_list, 4)) # => [-5, -15, -10, -30, -40, -52]
print(list_to_decimal(octal_list, 8)) # => [50, -144, -30, 5, 0, 1, -10]
```

It works using a function `list_to_decimal` that takes a list `lst` and a base `base`, which then uses [a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to interpret every element of `lst` as a number of `base`.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Something doesn't work here, function is correct but output is wrong. I checked some of converted numbers with online converter and they doesn't equal

Comment: Nevermind, second attempt succeed, evidently I had an fallacy somwhere in syntax. I think it was problem with the complexity of loops I used, before refactoring them. Before that, I tried to compare outputs of your answer and sharif's answer, which were inconsistent. After simplifying the code of entire program, issue dissapeared. Strange thing, I haven't met something like it before, becouse I didn't make any major changes

Comment: I also found [David Bowling's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601616/#comment95999978_54601616) quite enlightening. For example, in `binary_list`, the maximum value is `100`, which also happens to be the maximum value of the list if you interpret it as decimal values, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
binary_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 10, 10, 11, 100, 100, 11, 10, 0]
quaternary_list = [-11, -33, -22, -132, -220, -310]
octal_list = [62, -220, -36, 5, 0, 1, -12]

binary_list_do_dec = [int(str(i), 2) for i in binary_list]
quaternary_list_do_dec = [int(str(i), 4) for i in quaternary_list]
octal_list_do_dec = [int(str(i), 8) for i in octal_list]

print(binary_list_do_dec)
print(quaternary_list_do_dec)
print(octal_list_do_dec)
```

The output looks like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0]
[-5, -15, -10, -30, -40, -52]
[50, -144, -30, 5, 0, 1, -10]
```